# Routed page doesn't fill full screen

Tags: dart, flutter

I tried to push a new route and remove the old one with `Navigator.push`

```
Navigator.push(
    context,
    new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new MainPage()
    ),
);
```

So I was expecting to have the new screen overlap the old one entirely. But instead I got only 2/3(i guess) of the screen is filled. When I go back to previous screen and push new one again, it fills the entire screen.

[image: Only 2/3(i guess) of the screen is filled]

What I actually want is using `Navigator.pushReplacement` for the job

Comment: I forgot that I wanted to do some sign-in first then go to another route

Comment: That's very odd and certainly not expected - navigator.push normally pushes a full screen, unless your new page does something weird. You may need to post more of your code...